# Heroku - why can't I provision higher tier ClearDB (verification problem?)?

Tags: heroku

I've already added my credit card.

It's already been charged!

In fact, I am already using paid Dynos and the $9.99 version of ClearDB.

I want to up it to $49.99 (drift) but keep running into this error:

```
 Item could not be updated: 

Adding addon to unit-0-adhocs failed. Access to the addon cleardb:drift is limited to
customers with an established payment history. For more information, see  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification
```

Heroku support has been terrible. How can I solve this?

Comment: Having the same problem. Very frustrating.