# I can't set up Heroku ClearDB because lack of "establish a payment history"?

Tags: heroku, billing

I'm trying to add some services on Heroku, but it is failing because I don't have an "established payment history". We do have a credit card set up, but apparently that is not enough?

The heroku docs, as far as I can tell never define what is required to establish a payment history. I went ahead and created a paid dyno yesterday to see if that would do it, but that still hasn't done the trick.

Do I have to wait a month until Heroku bills me?

Apparently I'm not the only confused person: [Heroku - why can't I provision higher tier ClearDB (verification problem?)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68094127/heroku-why-cant-i-provision-higher-tier-cleardb-verification-problem)

So they're refusing my money because I haven't paid them money before? I don't understand...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this be something to take up w/ Heroku support?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, and I have, and this post is part of that. Heroku suggests posting to SO as part of their support strategy, and it's not uncommon for service providers to do this. Not only do they have internal staff who regularly monitor and reply to sites like SO via their #heroku tag, but they benefit from the persisted and public solution, making it less likely for the same problem to need to be handled in person again.

Comment: But billing isn't programming-related.

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah, you're right. At the same time, there's probably no other Stack Exchange site that it would fit under. Let me look around. I can probably transfer it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to contact Heroku support. They said in a support ticket what they don't say on their documentation. Basically you have to have paid some money, and that can be through previous services, or through a prepayment:

This is what they said:

```
Currently an established payment history with Heroku would consist of $30 or more in total spend across any 3 of the previous 6 months. In this case we would be able to perform a prepayment; which once completed would allow your account to access these new resources without having had $30 or more in spend from previous months.

I am happy to set up this prepayment for you so you can set up this addon. I would just need the following:

AMOUNT: Total amount of pre-payment in USD.
LAST MONTH: Last month that the pre-payment should be applied to (include year, can be estimated).
ACCOUNT: Team name or personal account email.
CARD: Last four digits of card
```

Comment: It's so annoying that they don't just allow immediate pre-payment on their website. If you need Performance-M immediately so you can quickly deploy a website for example a hackathon submission where a HTTPS is required that needs high memory and you don't have previous payment history setup and it's the weekend, then even if you submit a support request you won't get a response until 9am Monday Eastern Time when Heroku support works, and by that stage it might be too late for you.